# Remove border from html table created via pandas

Tags: python, html, pandas

I am using a python script to display dataframe on a webpage. I used `df.to_html` to convert my dataframe to HTML. However, by default, it sets the border to 0. I tried overriding it by having a custom css template but it didn't work.

Here is my pandas code:

```
ricSubscription.to_html(classes='mf')
```

Is there a parameter I can pass to set the border to zero while making this call?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be, you could parse the html and subsitute the `border` value but this does feel tedious

Comment: Google for css override. This should help you out.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`to_html()`  generates `<table border="1" class="dataframe">...`

You could just do:

```
ricSubscription.to_html().replace('border="1"','border="0"')
```

Also, to answer specifically, there does not appear to be anything you can pass. `border="1"` appears to be hardcoded:

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/e4cb0f8a6cbb5f0c89b24783baa44326e4b2cccb/pandas/core/format.py#L893

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks! Can the replace method be used to replace anything created by to_html()?

Comment: That's somewhat surprising that the value for border is hard coded like that.

Comment: @HimanshuGupta `df.to_html()` returns a `unicode` object, so you can use `find`, `replace`, `strip`, `upper`, `lower`, just like you would a string and replace anything you want.

Answer (score 12):

As of version 0.19.0, pandas `to_html()` borders can be changed in two ways:

1. Globally: `pd.options.html.border = 0`
2. Locally: `to_html(border = 0)`

**UPDATE 2019-07-11:**

Per @Hagbard's comment, my original global solution has been deprecated in favor of the following:
`pd.options.display.html.border = 0`

Docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html

Comment: Using your answer for the global settings, I get the following warning: "html.border has been deprecated, use display.html.border instead (currently both are identical)". Thus, "pd.options.display.html.border = 0" does the trick from now on.

Comment: @Hagbard - if you want to post an answer with the new version, please do.  Otherwise, I'll update mine with the new version.  Thanks.

Comment: It's fine for me if you update your answer. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 5):

If you are would like use `pd.Styler`. You could do something like this :

```
ricSubscription.style.set_table_attributes(
    'style="border-collapse:collapse"'
).set_table_styles([
    # Rest of styles
]).render()
```